# Problem installing PEAR with a chef recipe for vagrant

Tags: ruby, pear, chef-infra, vagrant

I am using Vagrant to create a development server locally. I am writing my own Chef recipe to install everything I need but I am running into problems.

Pear will not install as I think it is trying to pull down a version that is not stable. The error is:

```
No such file or directory - pear -d preferred_state=stable search PEAR
```

The recipe is as follows

```
# 
# Chef recipe for provisioning a LAMP
# development server.
#
require_recipe 'apt'
require_recipe 'apache2'
require_recipe 'apache2::mod_php5'
require_recipe 'php::module_gd'
require_recipe 'mysql::server'

php_pear "PEAR" do
    action :upgrade
end

php_pear "MDB2" do
    action :install
end

php_pear "MDB2#mysql" do
    action :install
end

# Grant access to this box...
ruby_block "Create database + execute grants" do
    block do

    require 'rubygems'
    Gem.clear_paths
    require 'mysql'

    m = Mysql.new('localhost', "root", node[:mysql][:server_root_password])
m.query("GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'10.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '#{node[:mysql][:server_root_password]}'")
m.query('FLUSH PRIVILEGES')

    end
end
```

How can I make PEAR install the last stable version?

Answer (score 1):

You are using pear to install pear itself? Isn't that strange?

The error message

```
No such file or directory
```

indicates that your recipe tries to use the full command as one executable, not as command and parameters.

```
pear -d preferred_state=stable search PEAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm doing to upgrade PEAR in my Ubuntu VM:

```
package "php-pear" do
  action :install
end
```

There's an Ubuntu package called `php-pear`, so this command will install the latest version